# What to do when multiplying a function by $0.5$

Tags: functions

This is for an assignment and I'm lost...
I was given $f(x)$ and it is a $W$ like shape
I have to transform the original into $0.5f(x-3)-4$ , which I understand all of but what to do with the 0.5. I am pretty sure I should compress the W but I don't know how much by.

If you need to know the original co-ordinates these are: 
$(-7,4) , (-2, -1) , (1, 2) , (4, -1),(9, 4)$ .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying a function $f(x)$ by a scalar $a>0$, scales the $y$ coordinate by a factor $a$. So if $a>1$ the graph gets stretched and if $0<a<1$ the graph is compressed.

The transformation in your question is the combination of a compression by a factor $1/2$, a horizontal shifting of $3$ units and a downward vertical shifting by $4$ units.

Comment: So to clarify, I would multiply all y coordinates by 1/2 and also would this be after or before the vertical and horizontal shifting?

Comment: @JacksonBarber: horizontal shifting and $y$-axis scaling commute, as easily seen. From the formula you wrote you first compress the graph and shift it to the right by $3$ units and *then* shift downwards by $4$ units.

Answer (score 1):

In general the transformation

$$k\cdot f(x)$$

scales vertically $f(x)$ with respect to the $x$ axis with a factor $k$.

[image]

- source http://xaktly.com/MathFunctions.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function $y = f(x)$, then $0.5\cdot f(x)$ means halving all the $y$ values for that function for the same $x$ values. As a hint, you can try to draw $y = x$ and $y = \frac{x}{2}$ in order to see how the graph of functions behave.